# Pyspark window that counts shows and no-shows of appointments with a day lag

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I want to add two columns to a pyspark dataframe that calculate the sum of True or False count in the psdln.awz column and do this for each unique psyin_iden_rn number. However with the condition that it only counts the sum of True or False for dates before the row it is calculating. Thus do with a lag of day. Also one thing it needs to do is to count each appointment and not just days.

## Sample data

data = [
(1, '2023-01-01', True),
(1, '2023-01-01', True),
(1, '2023-01-02', True),
(1, '2023-01-02', False),
(1, '2023-01-03', False),
(1, '2023-01-04', True),
(2, '2023-01-02', True),
(2, '2023-01-02', False),
(2, '2023-01-03', False),
]

columns = ['psyin_iden_rn', '`psdln.dat`', '`psdln.awz`']

output data = [
(1, '2023-01-01', True, 0 ,0),
(1, '2023-01-01', True, 0 ,0),
(1, '2023-01-02', True, 2, 0),
(1, '2023-01-02', False,2, 0),
(1, '2023-01-03', False,3, 1),
(1, '2023-01-04', True, 3, 2),
(1, '2023-01-02', True, 0 ,0),
(1, '2023-01-02', False, 0, 0),
(1, '2023-01-03', False, 1, 1),
]

columns = ['psyin_iden_rn', '`psdln.dat`', '`psdln.awz`', 'show_cnt' , 'no_show_cnt']

I have tried many differnt things but they all seem to lead to some of my conditions not being met. Either it starts counting based on the row it is calculating for an not only for the days before.
Or it has problems with dates that appear twice. For example, it only counts these dates once or as in the example code below it does not calculate the sum for days before but calculates the sum for anything before it (so also same day rows).

## Create a window specification

window_spec = Window.partitionBy('psyin_iden_rn').orderBy('`psdln.dat`').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

## Define the conditions for show_cnt and no_show_cnt

show_condition = (F.col('`psdln.awz`') == True)
no_show_condition = (F.col('`psdln.awz`') == False)

## Calculate show_cnt and no_show_cnt using window functions

df_contacten = (
df_contacten
.withColumn('show_cnt', F.sum(F.when(show_condition, 1).otherwise(0)).over(window_spec))
.withColumn('no_show_cnt', F.sum(F.when(no_show_condition, 1).otherwise(0)).over(window_spec))
)

How do I adjust or use this window so that I get an output as in the dataframe example above

Answer (score 0):

I think the output data content that you shared has some discrepancy. Here is the solution I have for you. Essentially I am using reverse total of show and no show conditions. Please drop the extra columns once you have the required ones.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
data = [ (1, '2023-01-01', True), (1, '2023-01-01', True), (1, '2023-01-02', True), (1, '2023-01-02', False), (1, '2023-01-03', False), (1, '2023-01-04', True), (2, '2023-01-02', True), (2, '2023-01-02', False), (2, '2023-01-03', False), ]
columns = ['psyin_iden_rn', 'psdln_dat', 'psdln_awz']
input=spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=columns)
true_cond = when(col('psdln_awz') == "true", 1).otherwise(0)
false_cond = when(col('psdln_awz') == "false", 1).otherwise(0)
input=input.withColumn("pt_ws_total",sum(true_cond).over(Window.partitionBy("psyin_iden_rn").orderBy(lit("A"))))
input=input.withColumn("pt_ws_n_total",sum(false_cond).over(Window.partitionBy("psyin_iden_rn").orderBy(lit("A"))))
window_spec=Window.partitionBy("psyin_iden_rn").orderBy(col('psyin_iden_rn').desc(),col('psdln_dat').desc())
input=input.withColumn("rvrs_ws_total",sum(true_cond).over(window_spec))
input=input.withColumn("rvrs_n_ws_total",sum(false_cond).over(window_spec))
input=input.sort('psyin_iden_rn','psdln_dat')
input=input.withColumn("show_cnt",col("pt_ws_total")-col("rvrs_ws_total"))
input=input.withColumn("no_show_cnt",col("pt_ws_n_total")-col("rvrs_n_ws_total"))
input.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in original approach was that the window function was counting the occurrences of True and False in the `psdln.awz` column for the current row's date as well as previous dates. You needed it to count only for dates before the current row's date, respecting unique `psyin_iden_rn` values, and considering each appointment separately, even if they occur on the same day

Check the below code. I have modified the window specification in the PySpark code to partition the data by `psyin_iden_rn` and order it by `psdln.dat`. The key change is in setting the range of the window to consider all rows up to but not including the current row `(rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1))`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType


data = [(1, '2023-01-01', True), (1, '2023-01-01', True), (1, '2023-01-02', True),
        (1, '2023-01-02', False), (1, '2023-01-03', False), (1, '2023-01-04', True),
        (2, '2023-01-02', True), (2, '2023-01-02', False), (2, '2023-01-03', False)]

columns = ['psyin_iden_rn', 'psdln.dat', 'psdln.awz']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df = df.withColumn('psdln.dat', F.col('psdln.dat').cast(DateType()))

daily_counts = df.groupBy('psyin_iden_rn', 'psdln.dat').agg(
    F.sum(F.when(F.col('psdln.awz') == True, 1).otherwise(0)).alias('daily_show_cnt'),
    F.sum(F.when(F.col('psdln.awz') == False, 1).otherwise(0)).alias('daily_no_show_cnt')
)

window_spec = Window.partitionBy('psyin_iden_rn').orderBy('psdln.dat').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

# Calculate cumulative counts
daily_counts = daily_counts.withColumn('show_cnt', F.sum('daily_show_cnt').over(window_spec))
daily_counts = daily_counts.withColumn('no_show_cnt', F.sum('daily_no_show_cnt').over(window_spec))

# Join back to the original dataframe to get the final result
result_df = df.join(daily_counts, ['psyin_iden_rn', 'psdln.dat'])

result_df.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but this still leads to the same problem where appointments on the same day still add to the count. As I showed in my example the count of show or no-show per day only needs to be added the day after, not the appointment after.

As you can see in the first three rows of the example output the count should still be 0 for both rows when the date is the same

Comment: I have updated the answer. The current code first calculates daily counts of shows and no-shows, then calculates their cumulative sums using a window function, ensuring that the count for each day is based only on the previous days. Finally, it joins these counts back to the original dataframe to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you this seems correct. Luckily I found another solution in the mean time, which is somewhat similar. In my current solution I calculate the show_cnt with window used in my first post. Afterwards I make a new window partitioned on date and psyin and calculate the minimal values over that window and save this in a seperate column. Lastly I replace the the values for this window with the minimim values.